# CSS Calc returning 0 but works in my fiddle

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to use css3 calc but it returns 0%.

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

On my local machine using this and then inspecting the element it displays:

```
width: calc(0%);
```

When I put it in a fiddle it seems to be working.

The part that is working is the blue content div being the proper width to be next to the sidebar where as on my local the content div have 0% width. It shows the content in the div but not the background colour blue.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/sL53dnvq/)

Is there any reason calc would be returning 0? I am using the latest version of firefox.

I have looked up alternatives to calc and none suit my needs other than javascript the approach. But I would like to avoid that method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Worth noting I was using Less

Comment: "Is there any reason calc would be returning 0?" - Yes, if the element is 100x wide (100% of 100px = 100px, minus 100px = 0). But not wanting to sound harsh, if it works in the fiddle then that isn't going to help us solve the problem much. Can you figure out the differences between the fiddle and your actual page?

Comment: @GolezTrol how could that element have a width of 100px when I am trying to set the width?

Comment: 100% is relative to the space it could occupy, right? 100% of the inner width of the parent so to say. So if that space is 100px, then there's your problem. Sorry if my explanation was unclear.

Comment: Are you using sass or less?

Comment: @atmd I am using less

Comment: in less you need to escape calc

Comment: @atmd throw it in an answer

Comment: "I have looked up alternatives to calc" - could you not use `display:table`? It does the same as you are trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/tLsfw3gn/

Comment: @Pete Yea your right it does do the same thing pretty much. And I was trying to use tables but I found that it kept screwing up my content section width. It would never be 100% always much smaller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In less you'll need to escape `calc`

try: `width: ~"calc(100% - 100px)";`

N.b. try [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) over jsfiddle. it lets you use sass and less.

Comment: I will look at jsbin.